# Jquery Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs, pagespeed, grunt-contrib-uglify

There is a a jquery module pattern in my project.I am not understanding what it is doing and why it is doing.

there is a custom plugin jquery.skInit.js that is made

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.skInit = function() {
    return this.each(function(i,element) {
      var e = jQuery.Event('skInit');
      e.container = $(element);
      $(':root').trigger(e);
    });
  };
  $.skInit = function(handler) {
    $(':root').on('skInit',handler);
  };
}(jQuery));


and skInit.cs jquery file


$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    //console.log('skInit');
    $(':root').skInit();



  });

and in remaining js files events are attached as follow. one of js file example 

$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $.skInit(function (e) {
        e.container.find('.csSpotTeaserInner').csSpotlightTeaserToggle();
        e.container.find(".sliderBarDiv").mCustomScrollbar();
    });
});
```

why this design pattern is writtern in this way...how it optimizes and improves performance...please explain if anyone can.My project is grunt project in which all javascripts are made uglify to bottom.js script a single one.

Comment: The code you've shown uses many patterns. Which one are you specifically referring to?

Comment: i just want to know benefit of making skInit() function

Comment: Compared to what? To write out `$(':root').on('skInit', function(e) { … })` in every of the modules that hook on the event?

Answer (score 0):

> why this design pattern is writtern in this way...how it optimizes and
>   improves performance...please explain if anyone can.

Not certain why the pattern is written in the manner that it is.

If the plugin contains authors name, perhaps contact author to ask why they used pattern ?

As to whether or not pattern optimizes and improves performance, what would pattern be compared to ? Event delegation using

```
$(document).on("customEvent", ".element1, .element2", handler);
$(document).trigger("customEvent");
```

?

You could try to create a test for which pattern performs more operation over a period at [jsperf](http://jsperf.com).

Attempted to interpret process at Question at comments within `js` at stacksnippets

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.skInit = function() {
    return this.each(function(i, element) {
      // create jQuery event
      var e = jQuery.Event('skInit');
      // cache parent element for event
      e.container = $(element);
      // `:root` : `document.documentElement` : `<html>`,
      // or root element of document
      $(':root').trigger(e);
    });
  };
  $.skInit = function(handler) {
    // call attached handlers when custom event is triggered
    $(':root').on('skInit', handler);
  };
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  // add handler to be called
  $.skInit(function(e) {
    // `e.container` : `:root` : `html` element
    console.log(e.container);
    e.container.find('#abc').css("color", "green");
    e.container.find("#123").css("color", "orange");
  });
  // trigger `skInit` custom event,
  // calling handler passed to `$.skInit` above
  $(":root").skInit()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="abc">abc</div>
  <div id="123">123</div>
</body>

</html>
```